# Random Sagepay success URL callbacks

Tags: opayo

we are using SP form integration which has been working well for some time now. Recently we appear to be getting occasional ( maybe once a fortnight) repeat callbacks of success URLs which is very odd. To put that in context, the volume of total purchase transactions is low  - maybe 5 or 10 a week.

The callbacks contain valid data but are for purchases which were successfully completed as much as 2 months previously. The time intervals seems to be completely random.

Don't have much debugging info to go on yet other than that the callbacks were initiated from the USA so I was wondering if Sagepay would be the initiator for some reason?

Comment: Update on this after anotehr occurrence just now - the callback is allegedly coming from bingbot ( HTTP_USER_AGENT=[Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)]) but how/why would they be trying to access/index a callback that only Sagepay should know about??...

Answer (score 0):

There could be plenty of sources of this re-callback.
It's probably best to ignore them by not processing the callback if it's already been processed (with some sort of flag on the original transaction on your system), and then perhaps automatically log the occurrences with the IP address and headers if it's already been processed.
You should already be ignoring repeat callbacks with the same transaction id anyway, but then if you're worried, I would contact Sage Pay with the logs for them to investigate :)